# Return a value from a range in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, range, lookup

I am trying to do a very simple range lookup in MS Access.

I basically have two tables:

[image: Employees]

[image: TaxRates]

I am looking for a query that will be able to go find the appropriate range of the salary and return the correct tax rate.

I started off with this as my base:

```
SELECT IIf(Salary Between 1000 And 2000,10,20)
FROM Employees;
```

But I am not making any sort of progress.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method is to use a correlated subquery, e.g.:

```sql
select e.*, (select top 1 t.taxrate from taxrates t where t.to > e.salary order by t.to)
from employees e
```

Or using [`between`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/between-and-operator-a435878d-63f7-4825-8c31-999432ae8223):

```
select e.*, (select top 1 t.taxrate from taxrates t where e.salary between t.to and t.from)
from employees e
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`left join`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-join-right-join-operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb) in the following way:

```
select e.*, t.taxrate
from employees e left join taxrates t on (e.salary between t.to and t.from)
```

Note that MS Access cannot represent this type of join in query Design View (i.e. a join with 'calculated' join criteria as opposed to joining on equal field values), but this is still valid SQL which may be successfully evaluated by the JET database engine.

---

In all of the above, I've assumed that your tables are called `Employees` & `TaxRates`, change these to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
SELECT Salary.*, TaxRate.TaxRate
FROM Salary, TaxRate
WHERE Salary BETWEEN From and TO;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a very simple solution. Much appreciated