# I have two tables I would like to update from table A to table B . Fills in the blanks according between condition ID

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables I would like to update from table A to table B. Fills in the blanks according between condition ID.

table a

```
ID  color

1   red
2   
3   
4   
5   blue
6   
7   white
8   
9   
10  
11  
12  yellow
13  
14
15
16
17
18
```

table b

```
color   from   to  
blue      5     6  
red       1     4  
white     7    11  
yellow   12    18
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this using joins with calculated criteria, e.g.:

```
update t1 inner join t2 on (t1.id between t2.from and t2.to) set t1.color = t2.color
```

This is very similar to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103512/7531598).